# 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I use django and elasticseach inside for search engine,Everything worked out,but recently have this error
when i want change everything in database, for example when i wan't to create an new user from django admin have this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/add/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'gunicorn',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'djangoratings',
 'taggit',
 'bootstrap_toolkit',
 'mptt',
 'postman',
 'redisboard',
 'django_extensions',
 'avatar',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'dajaxice',
 'dajax',
 'endless_pagination',
 'easy_pjax',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_nose',
 'haystack',
 'queued_search',
 'saved_searches',
 'darkoob.book',
 'darkoob.social',
 'darkoob.search',
 'darkoob.group',
 'darkoob.post',
 'darkoob.comments',
 'darkoob.migration',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  372.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  69.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  223.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in add_view
  121.                                                extra_context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  223.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1007.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  740.         obj.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  546.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  664.                                    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  170.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/vahid/Workspace/darkoob/darkoob/social/models.py" in create_user_profile
  109.         UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in create
  149.         return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  402.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  546.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  664.                                    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  170.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/signals.py" in handle_save
  47.                 index.update_object(instance, using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/indexes.py" in update_object
  266.                 backend.update(self, [instance])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py" in update
  177.         self.conn.bulk_index(self.index_name, 'modelresult', prepped_docs, id_field=ID)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py" in decorate
  96.             return func(*args, query_params=query_params, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py" in bulk_index
  389.                                  query_params=query_params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py" in send_request
  253.         prepped_response = self._decode_response(resp)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py" in _decode_response
  280.             json_response = response.json()

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/auth/user/add/
Exception Value: 'dict' object is not callable
```

why this error ocurred and how i can fixed it?

Comment: Check if your `pyelastic` search supports your `elasticsearch` backend version.

Comment: Should `json_response = response.json()` be `json_response = response.json`? Your error string implies that you're trying to call a dictionary as if it was a function.

Comment: @PhilipAmyWright you sat this error from `pyelasticsearch` library? i think i should not change it.

Comment: Oh, no, I thought that line was yours. Nevermind then.

Comment: This version requires elasticsearch 0.19.2 or above. `Workspace/elasticsearch-0.90.3$ bin/elasticsearch -v
Version: 0.90.3, Build: 5c38d60/2013-08-06T13:18:31Z, JVM: 1.7.0_25`

Comment: `Workspace/darkoob$ grep json_response * -r` has no result. so this line not in my code

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py`, error from this line.

Comment: mr. @kroolik , i don't think for version of `elasticsearch` becuase i and my team use a use a version of the same, but they haven't this error:-S

Comment: Can you post the `create_user_profile` function from social/models.py, and your `UserProfile` model?

Comment: yes i do it, [see model](https://bitbucket.org/darkoob/darkoob/src/1b71174192d548bd4c885a55ea7f1b71ed98335b/darkoob/social/models.py?at=alpha). when i do every change in database this error occured, create user is an example. i confused!

Comment: This error started from `base.py` and ended from 'pyelasticsearch/client.py' :| i don't think it's from my code

Comment: If you change `UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)` to `UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance, gender='M')`, what's the effect? I can see that `gender` is not optional in your `UserProfile` model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using an early release of the `requests` library. The API for the `.json` attribute changed; since at least 1.0 of the library it is now a function.

The `pyelastic` requires `requests` 1.0 or newer; upgrade the library.